# convert two channels into a single channel with ffmpeg

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg

I have some .wav files and I would like to convert their frequency (fs) and number of channels (nchannels). I am using ffmpeg on a jupyter notebook, python3.6. I used the following command and it works.

```
cmd= 'ffmpeg -i %s -ar %d -ac %d %s.wav'%(filepath,fs,nchannel,wavfilename)
os.system(cmd)
```

However, I dont know how does ffmpeg convert two channels into a single channel, probably takes an average of two signal? I need to take the max of the two channels. I couldn`t see it in ffmpeg documentation. How can I achieve that? thanks

Comment: If the two channels encode different microphone inputs, then you'll lose some information, by picking one channel. If you take a per-sample max value, then the result could be distorted.

Comment: thanks for mentioning that, it helped. I was thinking to take the stronger signal on average itself, but I have to find out before ahead which signal is stronger.